# Pasting same cell on different rows as value is replaced

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

This sort of follows up from my previous few questions on the same workbook.

I have two sheets, the first being `Car Search`, which contains a form (NOT a VBA form, just a normal table that appears like a form) to fill in. The second sheet is `Raw Data`, and will contain all the information entered in the `Car Search` sheet. It will be displayed row by row (see 2nd image).

In the `Raw Data` sheet, I am using the formula `=""&'Car Search'!B3` to copy the contents of cell `B3` in the `Car Search` spreadsheet.

My question is: If I had a new `Car ID` value, how can that automatically be entered into the row below?

Essentially, I am trying to use the form to capture all data for new cars coming in, and then I would like all that data to appear in the second sheet in their respective rows/columns.

[image: Car Search sheet]
[image: Raw Data sheet]

Any help much appreciated! :)

Comment: is it still in UI design phase... or do we have  some VBA code? If yes, plz post.

Comment: hi, it's just a simple table that I created, it's not a VBA form, I would like to be able to do this without VBA.

Comment: i am not sure, without vba, you can move to next row and dump data, but wait and see if some one comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

Good news!

You need to use VBA:

```
Sub Range_Copy_Examples()

    Worksheets("Car Search").Range("B3").Copy Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("=OFFSET(Sheet3!B1,0,0,COUNTA(B1:B300)+1,1)")


End Sub
```

However there is a small bug where it keeps pasting across past values, so I have suggested an alternative macro below

### Re-edit:

A more mechanical way to make macro work (hopefully someone can improve on it) looks like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Car Search").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Car Search").Activate

End Sub
```

This works as follows:

- in `Car Search`, have cell B3 selected the whole time
- in `Raw Data`, select the cell with the last value in the column where you want you `Car Search!B3` data pasted (you only have to do this once)
- press Run on the macro (easy enough to just [record one yourself](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2.html))
- go back to `Car Search` and change the value of B3, press `Ctrl-Enter` to keep the same cell selected after changing value, then press the same macro button without changing a thing.

If someone could add so that when pressing Ctrl-Enter on `Car Search!B3` the `Raw Data` gets automatically added without having to manually run the macro, it would be fully automated!

Comment: thanks, I have tried this and copied it down the column. The issue now is whenever I update the `Car ID` value, all the values in the column are updated with that exact value. 

What I want is for it to capture a new value that I enter

Comment: You should use autofill (the handle at the bottom right corner of your selected cell) in order to have the formula apply for each row i.e. on row 4 your formula should say `=IF(B4<>"",B4,"")` and on the 5th `=IF(B5<>"",B5,"")`

Comment: You can also do this by selecting the cell with the above formula and pressing the following combination: `Ctrl-C , Ctrl-Space , Ctrl-V`

Comment: that doesn't work across the sheets. The first sheet (`Car Search`) has `Car ID` which is in cell B3. That's the value I am trying to copy over to the second sheet (`Raw Data`). But everytime I enter a new `Car ID` value, I would like the value to be copied over to a new row in the `Raw Data` sheet

Comment: so you replace the value of B3 with a new one each time? why not add next value on next row?

Comment: yep, I replace the value in cell B3 with a new one each time. And I would like that new value to be copied over to a new cell in the `Raw Data` sheet. I would also want the previous values that I entered to remain in the previous rows.

How do I add next value on next row?

Comment: I have never used VBA before, I clicked Visual Basic the Developer tab, how do I add the code into VBA?

Comment: copy-paste the code into an empty VBA sheet and click run (the green play button below the menu bar)

Comment: is an empty VBA sheet a new module?